Pi not setting RTC time via NTP when saved as main.py
I have written some micropython code thats working as I had hoped in Thonny (making a gadget to assist my wife remembering which boob was last used when breastfeeding). I have used some code from "Lutz" youtube tutorial to set a Pi pico's RTC using a NTP. However when I save this code as "main.py" and disconnect the pi from the PC then power it up, it connects to wifi but the RTC displays as 00:00 (doesn't appear to have been set by the NTP). If I then press stop in thonny and run the script via thonny the RTC is set correctly.
I have tried using sleep intervals up to 1 min between connecting to wifi and setting the RTC however the RTC is still displaying as 00:00. The displayed time does then progress correctly every min.
import network
import socket
from time import sleep
import machine
from machine import I2C
from pico_i2c_lcd import I2cLcd
from machine import RTC
import rp2
import sys
import utime as time
import usocket as socket
import ustruct as struct


I2C_ADDR     = 0x27
I2C_NUM_ROWS = 2
I2C_NUM_COLS = 16
time = RTC()

i2c = I2C(0, sda=machine.Pin(0), scl=machine.Pin(1), freq=100000)
lcd = I2cLcd(i2c, I2C_ADDR, I2C_NUM_ROWS, I2C_NUM_COLS)

ssid = "SSID"
password = "PASSWORD"

button_L = machine.Pin(16, machine.Pin.IN, machine.Pin.PULL_UP)
button_R = machine.Pin(18, machine.Pin.IN, machine.Pin.PULL_UP)
button_press_L = button_L.value()
button_press_R = button_R.value()

last_boob = "00:00"
current_boob = "0"

def connect():
    #Connect to WLAN
    wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
    wlan.active(True)
    wlan.connect(ssid, password)
    while wlan.isconnected() == False:
        lcd.move_to(0,0)
        lcd.putstr("Waiting for connection...")
        print('Waiting for connection...')
        sleep(1)
        
#     print(wlan.ifconfig())

try:
    connect()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    machine.reset()
    
sleep (60)

# NTP-Host
NTP_HOST = 'pool.ntp.org'

# get time from NTP Server
def getTimeNTP():
    NTP_DELTA = 2208988800
    NTP_QUERY = bytearray(48)
    NTP_QUERY[0] = 0x1B
    addr = socket.getaddrinfo(NTP_HOST, 123)[0][-1]
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    try:
        s.settimeout(1)
        res = s.sendto(NTP_QUERY, addr)
        msg = s.recv(48)
    finally:
        s.close()
    ntp_time = struct.unpack("!I", msg[40:44])[0]
    return time.gmtime(ntp_time - NTP_DELTA + GMT_OFFSET)

# copy time to RTC
def setTimeRTC():
    tm = getTimeNTP()
    rtc.datetime((tm[0], tm[1], tm[2], tm[6] + 1, tm[3], tm[4], tm[5], 0))


while True:
    
    button_press_L = button_L.value()
    button_press_R = button_R.value()
    print(f"L: {button_press_L} , R: {button_press_R}")

    current_time = time.datetime()
    display_time = "%02d:%02d"%(current_time[4:6])
    
    if button_press_L == 0:
        last_boob = display_time
        current_boob = "L"
    elif button_press_R == 0:
        last_boob = display_time
        current_boob = "R"
    
    lcd.clear
    lcd.move_to(0,0)
    lcd.putstr(f"Time now: {display_time}")
    lcd.move_to(0,1)
    lcd.putstr(f"Last {current_boob} @: {last_boob}")

    



